# In Angular2/4/5, How to bind the Data to FrontView If it is coming like an array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to get data in front of UserName and Email of home.html. But Now I'm getting like below[image] 
I'm getting data in console as the below image
[image]
What may be the error/ How to bind these type of data in HTML with Angular..
Now **home.html** is below..Commented/non commented code, both are not working

```
 <div class="row" *ngIf="userClaims">
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span>Username :{{userClaims.Name}}</span>
        <br>
        <span>Email : {{userClaims}}</span>
        <br>
        <!-- <div *ngFor="let order of userClaims" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 15px; margin: 5px 0;">
          OrderNumber : {{ order.Id }} <br>
          P_O_Number : {{ order.Address }} <br>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.userClaims= this.userService.userClaims;
  }
```

Below is the service code **app-data.service.ts**

```
sendMobileNo(mobno) {
        var data = "MobileNo=" + mobno;
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
       var url=this.uihelper.CallWebAPIUrlNew("/Tenant/GetTenantsByMobile")+"?"+data;
        return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => {
           var data = response.json();
             //this.userClaims = response.json();
             //this.userClaims(data);
           this.userClaims=data;
        });
}
```

I need to know , **if the data is coming as array like in above image, how to present it in HTML page**..Can anyone help me out..Thanks In Advance

My **register component** from which I'm calling app-data.service and navigating to home component is 
**register.ts**

```
    OnSubmit(mobno){
    this.regService.sendMobileNo(mobno).subscribe((data : any)=>{
      //this.userClaims = data;
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage,{data});
      //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    },
   (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
     this.isLoginError = true;
   });
  }
```

Comment: can you create a plunkr or stackblitz link

Comment: you are not subscribing it

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one value (and you know that it will be always just that one), you could use

```
var data = response.json();
if(data && data.length == 1) {
    this.userClaim = data[0];
}
```

But in this case I would acutally recomment you to modify your back-end to just return one object instead of an array.

If you have an unknown amount of data in your array use a loop

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="userClaims">
    <div *ngFor="let order of userClaims" class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <span>Username :{{order.Name}}</span>
                <br>
                <span>Email : {{order.Email}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just wrote this snippets here, so I can't guarantee that it's completely accurate.

Comment: For displaying data[0], (one object of array), What should be the HTML  code..Above HTML is not working

Comment: If I use your HTML with a mock object like `this.userClaims = {"Name": "foo", "Email": "bar"};` it shows up. What exactly is not working?

Comment: if this is object `this.userClaims=0:{Id:"1", Address:"shdgdg"};` as shown in above image

Comment: In that image you see the object in debug mode (with array keys), actually it looks about like this `var data = [{"Id":"1", "Address":"shdgdg", "Name": "xxxxx"}]` this is what should be returned by your response.json(); And then you assign `this.userClaims = data[0];` so userClaims will contain `{"Id":"1", "Address":"shdgdg", "Name": "xxxxx"}` the first object of your array and with that the HTML works.

Answer (score 0):

An `Observable` is cold, meaning that you have to subscribe on it to get it called and have a value.
 `map` operator is used to parse your response in the desired format and it returns an observable which shall be subscribed.

```
sendMobileNo(mobno) {
        var data = "MobileNo=" + mobno;
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
       var url=this.uihelper.CallWebAPIUrlNew("/Tenant/GetTenantsByMobile")+"?"+data;
        return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) =>response.json());


}
```

I assume you have injected your service in home.ts
invoke the method and subscribe it to get the value.

```
onSubmit(mobno:any){
    this.userService.sendMobileNo(mobno).subscribe(response=>{
       this.userClaims= response});
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name mobno..Actually, I'm calling service from **register.ts** and for the subscribe event I should pass the data from **register.ts(register component)** to **home.ts(home component)** I wiil add subscribe event of register component

Comment: Added above register.ts @Vikas

Comment: I don't have access to the rest of your code, based on my assumption I gave the solution,  modify your classes accordingly or share more code so that I can help you

Comment: `<form id="register-form3" #registrationForm="ngForm (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(MobileNo.value)">
    <ion-list id="register-list11">
      <ion-item id="register-input8">
        <ion-label>
          Phone Number
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" #MobileNo ngModel name="MobileNo"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button id="register-button7" ion-button color="positive" block on-click="goToBankList()">
      Search Bank
    </button>
  </form>`  This is my **register.html**. Now I should show data in home.html based on mobno entered

Comment: @ShaileshBhat i have updated my answer based on the code you have shared, what I understand is on `onSubmit ` event you  want to make a http call?

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
   onSubmit(mobno:any){
   this.userService.sendMobileNo(mobno).subscribe(response=>{
    this.userClaims= response});
   }
  }` yes..But it is of register component. I should show **Data(result) from that http call** in home.ts(home component/HTML page)..the code posted here by me is of **home.ts**. It is not correct. how to access result from service in **ngoninit(){} of home.ts**

Comment: @ShaileshBhat update your question with relevant code and the desired functionality?

Comment: So you want to call the http method in register component and get the result in home component?

Comment: Yes Sir..You understood my requirement @Vikas

Comment: @ShaileshBhat you should use [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) operator for above scenario.